# argument naming rule in haskell

Tags: variables, haskell, arguments, naming-conventions

For what reason is it not allowed for an argument with the same name to appear more than once in the same equation?
Examples:

```
f a a = show a

d && d = d
_ && _ = False
```

> Technically speaking, formal parameters (The Report calls these variables.) are also patterns---it's just that they never fail to match a value. As a "side effect" of the successful match, the formal parameter is bound to the value it is being matched against. For this reason patterns in any one equation are not allowed to have more than one occurrence of the same formal parameter (a property called linearity §3.17, §3.3, §4.4.3).

Comment: What would be the semantic of that? For example if you called `f` like `f 1 2` what should be the result?

Comment: @PedroRodrigues- I've wanted this myself many times!  It would be the same as "f x y | x == y = ...." (if x /= y, it would just fall back to the next pattern).  Can someone here, who is familiar with the language spec process, tell us why this isn't allowed!  Is there a reason, or was it just never considered?

Comment: WinGHCi: `Prelude> let _ && _ = False` => `(0.00 secs, 0 bytes)` =>
`Prelude> 5 && 6` => `False`

Comment: @jamshidh What would that mean for types that don't have an `Eq` instance? Or even for two arguments of different types?

Comment: @fjh- It would mean the exact same thing that `f x y | x == y = ....` would mean if `x` or `y` don't have an `Eq` instance, or if they are different types- a compiler error.

Comment: But why bake in a specific syntax expression just for `==`? Guards are general and take any predicate.

Comment: @Impredicative It makes pattern matching a little bit more powerful. I like that bit of Prolog and Erlang.

Comment: @Impredicative- because, as much as one might wish to deny it, (==) is special....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [this mailing list post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.functional/k1RkbOkGoPk/U5s4wX4d4u8J), this was allowed in Miranda and was a common source of bugs: people would name two variables the same way by accident and have trouble discovering such a subtle mistake. So Haskell disallows it in favor of explicitly adding guards.

I personally think this is also much gentler on the poor reader of your code, who as a result of this rule need not keep in mind all the different variables that are in scope at the site of a pattern match to see whether the pattern will actually match everything or not.

Comment: Good answer- I want to add something also....  Perl Regular Expressions basically allow something similar with backreferences (ie- backslashes followed by a single digit number in the RE, like this `/(\w+) \1/`, which matches the same word separated by a space).   Perhaps it would be less error prone if Haskell had a backreference char itself, like `f x \x = ....`

Comment: Hi @Daniel, thanks. However I can't say I understand what you mean in your personal opinion. Could you write it in different words or even try to illustrate with an example?

Comment: @tomas Well, I guess when it comes right down to it I'm just restating the first paragraph. But the point I'm trying to make is that if you have a function with many arguments, each of which is a pattern, like `foo (Person name age id) (Person name' age' id') (Company name location ceo)` or something like that, it would be tiring for a person reading this code to decipher which of these variables match all values and which are "special" -- e.g. did you notice that this pattern only matches when you happen to pass it a person and a company that share the same name?

Comment: @tomas Additionally, I'm imagining that somebody inevitably says, "it would be really handy if this was extended so that when `mySuperDuperConstant` is in scope as a global variable I can match against that with an implied equality, too. Like, `mySuperDuperConstant = 42; foo mySuperDuperConstant = 0; foo _ = 1` should map `42` to `0` and everything else to `1`.". Suddenly the problem is multiplied ten-fold: you need to check not just other variables in the same pattern, but *every variable that's in scope*. I argue that long argument lists are not so different from long global constant lists.

Comment: @Daniel, very nice. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can't define

```
d && d = d
_ && _ = False
```

because you're trying to use pattern matching on a variable.

Pattern matching only works on data constructors, so

```
True && True = True
```

is OK, but

```
d && d = d
```

means "take the first argument (let's call it `d`) and the second argument (let's call it `d`) and..." but the compiler interrupts you saying
"no, wait, don't call them both `d`, I won't know which one you mean!" and you say
"But I only want you to do this if they're the same anyway" and the compiler says
"That's not what names are for - test with `a == b` for that. Please don't check for equality without using `==`, I don't know what you mean by equality unless you define `==` by making your data an instance of the `Eq` typeclass, in which case, I'd like you to warn me in the type signature so I can get the correct definition for `==` compiled in."

When you say `f a a = show a`, and then ask it to `show 3 4` the compiler says "which one do you want me to show?"